# C# not outputting to console

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I'm sure there's some simple answer, but none of the other Stack Overflow posts has helped me.  My code will not log to the Console, and it's hard to do anything useful with that state of affairs.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Learning
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Debug.Log ("this?");
            Debug.Print ("How about this?");
            Console.WriteLine ("WORK");
            Console.ReadLine ();
        }
    }
}
```

I've been able to write to the console before, I don't know why it's being persnickety now.

Comment: which one Debug or console ?

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: I'm not getting anything at all.  Maybe I'm looking in the wrong spot?  The output used to show me the Console.WriteLine() calls.  Where would I look for the Debug calls?

Comment: @Jasen, I'm just clicking the Run Item button

Comment: Debug does not have method Log perhaps use Debug.Write

Comment: You probably want Debug.WriteLine(), which would write to the output window of the attached debugger.

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but what kind of application is it? You can check (and change) it to a Console app in the Solution Properties.

Comment: It was a Console App, but I recently did a Save As operation, and that may have changed it.  I'm working with MonoDevelop though, and can't figure out how to change it.  (I have Solution Options, but nothing that looks like changing the application type.)

Comment: I've added the MonoDevelop tag to your post, since that's pertinent information and changes the answers.

Comment: I must have done something really weird.  I started a new file and things are working fine now.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Probably because your code doesn't actually compile. `Log()` is a static [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.log%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of Debugger, not Debug, and it takes three arguments: level, category, and message.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(1, "category", "this?");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print ("How about this?");
    Console.WriteLine ("WORK");
    Console.ReadLine ();
}
```

It's worth noting that Debug/Debugger methods will not do you any good unless you are Debugging.  To start a debugging session in mono, go to the Run -> Debug

Comment: @ChadF are you actually building/rebuilding your project before attempting to run it?  Go to the Build menu -> Rebuild, then run your project.

Comment: Only other issue should be whether your project is a console application.

Comment: @DanField true, although with that Main method signature, let's hope that it is. Nonetheless, it would be a good thing to check.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check what kind of application you are using. For example, if you are making a Forms Application, you won't have access to the `Console` functions.

You can change this by going into the Solution Properties, and changing it from a Windows Forms Application to a Console Application. This won't have any effect on your program, other than it will run a Console alongside.

[image]

[image]