# Best way to always keep console open

Tags: c#

Hello I wanted to know what is the best way to keep a console open forever? I want the fastest way, the most stable way, basically the best way to keep it open forever untill I close it.

I have recently been using the code below, but someone has said while loops are not good? or something like that, or storing stuff inside them isn't good? I basically just wanted your guys advice on what is the overall best way to do this? or a few of the best ways...

```
while (true) //in Program.cs in void Main
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Ehm, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To always keep the console app open, until I close it... I made that perfectly clear. So when whenever or whatever I type it doesn't close.

Comment: Define "until I close it" - a while true loop doesn't do anything to prevent me from simply closing the window.

Comment: I shouldn't have to explain this, but I will... It is a socket server.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30609812/3073006)

Comment: you should have to explain it :)  that's the point of this site

Comment: I shouldn't have to explain what my code does... All I need to know is what is another alternative method other than Console.ReadKey(); as I can't use that due to I type in the console to speak to my players (mass message)

Comment: He explained his question. I don't see anything wrong with it. How does one keep a console app open forever.

Comment: Well the whole point of asking this question on this site is to get an answer for your project to improve/knowledge. In order to give a suitable answer,  You should provide a maximum of information. Keeping console open can be done by not ending the app because the app is still in process.  Since we have no idea of your programmation skills we can't assume that you are talking about a socket server or just leave it open until you need it.

Answer (score 5):

Do a simple Console Application and it will be open until the end of the execution. If you close the console you close the app. If you dont need the console it will remain open until the app is done running (so no loop or anything) and when you will be ready to use it, it will still be there waiting for you.

EDIT: 
You might want to consider doing a Service application then. You wont have any console running and the application will be standing there behind and no one will see a black box and risk of closing it by mistake.  You can then stop it with the Service Panel.   The core of your service will be a simple thread waiting on a signal (a player connect).  so your app run 24/7 without any problem and can be close easily.

Comment: This answer is not helpful... I want to keep it open 24/7 untill I hit "X" due to it being a game socket emulator... if it closes my players can't connect. And I have a lot of code finishing at starting at different times. I would do console.readkey(); but I type in there to send messages to the players

Comment: @LiamHardy Your comment does not align with your post - one says "I have recently been using ...`console.readkey();`" and another says that essentially you can't as "I type in there to send messages to the players". This sends somewhat mixed message to people trying to answer your question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You are right :) And if Liam needs a suggestion to keep both functionalities I would still recommand the Service solution with an Console application that he can create to connect himself to the server and then type his message and leave when needed

Comment: @LiamHardy Added an answer after your clarification in this comment.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with a loop. I would have a command that can be input to close the window from a text input though. Something like:

```
string s = "";
while (s != "kill")
    s = Console.ReadLine();
```

Some times `while(true)` loops can be dangerous because they will always run but I feel a while loop is fine. I have used this code for servers and the like. It has never been a problem for me.

Comment: `while(true)` would be a performance hog. This solution wouldn't.

Comment: It would be if he typed a lot into the console but since `Console.ReadKey()` waits for a key it performs the same... Unless he types alot.

Answer (score 0):

So in your comment you say:

> I want to keep it open 24/7 untill I hit "X"

In this case, do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press X to stop");
do
{
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        // Do something
    }
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.X);

Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
```

As other people are pointing out, `while(true)` would be a performance hog.

Maybe (there is not enough info to know that) what you want to do as well is to start a thread before the loop, and kill it after the loop. This way your functions run parallel to the loop but you are in control of killing it whenever you want (pressing X). To do this in a clean way, follow the [example at the bottom of the page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx).

...or by brute force:

```
Console.WriteLine("Running the process");
System.Threading.Thread workerThread = new System.Threading.Thread(MyFunction);
workerThread.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Press X to stop");
do
{
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        // Do something
    }
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.X);

workerThread.Abort();

Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
```